# Is Schoolyard Team Picking Fair?

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Two captains are picking teams for dodgeball. They both will pick players in order of their skill level, best to worst. John gets first pick, Sarah gets the next two picks, and John gets the 4th. If skill in dodgeball is normally distributed, are players 1 and 4 guaranteed to have a mean skill level equal to players 2 and 3?

Comment: What do you think about the problem?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been here for a couple of days without a thorough answer,
so maybe some comments, references and simulated ressults will help. (This post has been revised and describes a simplified selection procedure--after an exchange of Comments with
@Tonyk.)

My interpretation is that the two team captains each select two
players in the specified order, making two teams of three people,
the minimal number for a game of dodgeball according to rules
posted on several Internet sites.

Let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)},X_{(4)}$ denote the order statistics of
a random sample of size $n = 4$ from $Norm(\mu, \sigma).$

It seems you want to know whether the expected value of the average of $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(4)}$ is the same as the expected value of the
average of $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$.

Without loss of generality, we can use a standard
normal distribution. I think a complete analytic
solution may be a bit tedious. A general discussion is given in Chapter 15 of Kendall, Stuart, & Ord (5e); particular values of $E(X_{(i)})$ are
derived and tabled in [Headrick and Pant, Table 3](http://opensiuc.lib.siu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1008&context=epse_pubs). In particular,
$$E(X_{(4)}) = \frac{3}{\sqrt{\pi}} - \frac{6\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{2})}{\pi^{3/2}} = 1.0294$$ and 
$$E(X_{(3)}) = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{\pi}} + \frac{18\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{2})}{\pi^{3/2}} = 0.2970.$$

By symmetry, one must have 
$E(X_{(4)}) = - E(X_{(1)})$ and  $E(X_{(3)}) = - E(X_{(2)})$.
Thus $E[(X_{(1)} + X_{(4)})/2] = 0$ and $E[(X_{(2)} + X_{(3)})/2] = 0$ so that neither team has a systematic advantage.

In the simulation below we use 100.000 choices of four people
to get approximate results (about 2 significant digits) and show figures. The averages of the two people chosen for each team seem similar: in expectations (essentially 0),
standard deviations (both about 0.55), and distributional shapes (shown in histograms). Even though there is no systematic advantage
to either team, the standard deviations and plots indicate that
there can be considerable variability in overall ability each time four people are
chosen.

```
 m = 10^5;  n = 4
 x = rnorm(m*n);  DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)  # m x n: each row has n choices
 ORD = apply(DTA, 1, sort) # n x m: each row has m sim order statistics
 a.14 = (ORD[1,]+ORD[4,])/2;  mean(a.14);  sd(a.14)
 ## 0.002015859  # approx 0
 ## 0.5435122
 a.23 = (ORD[2,]+ORD[3,])/2;  mean(a.23);  sd(a.23)
 ## 0.002232982  # approx 0
 ## 0.5456485
 rowMeans(ORD) # approx the values from H & P
 ## -1.0258067 -0.2937697  0.2982357  1.0298384
```

[image]

Furthermore, captains are likely both to be relatively satisfied or both unsatisfied because the correlation between the two
averages is about 0.67.

```
 cor(a.14, a.23)
 ##   0.676061
```

Here is a scatterplot of the two averages from the first 30,000
groups of four players selected. (Plotting all 100,000 gives
an uninformative blob.)

[image]

Finally, we show histograms of the simulated values of the four
order statistics, where vertical lines indicate means. Notice
the symmetry for the first and fourth, and for the second and third
order statistics.

[image]

Comment: what an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, but this is as even as you can get

Comment: The question can perhaps also be interpreted as "Is the expected advantage of John's team over Sarah's team equal to zero?" And the answer to that question is: yes, of course.

Comment: @Tonyk: You are right about no expected advantage if only four are chosen. I saw your comment after my post, intended no disagreement. Change 10 to 4 in my simulation for that result. I somewhat arbitrarily used 4 out of 10 because Internet descriptions of dodgeball mention larger teams.

Comment: @BruceET: What is important here is whether the team size is even or odd. If each team has an even number of players, then by symmetry the expected advantage of each captain is zero. Try your simulation with 8 or 12 instead of 10. (As a sanity check, it is easy to see that a team size of 1 is unfair to Sarah!)

Comment: @Tonyk: Possible miscommunication here? For 8, 10, and 12, I got a discrepancy in avg quality that is clearly above the level of simulation noise.

Comment: @BruceET: That can't be right! There is a measure-preserving transformation $X \mapsto 2\mu - X$ that simply reflects all skill levels about the mean, and preserves team selection if the team size is even. It also multiplies the skill difference between the two teams by $-1$. So the mean skill difference must be zero.

Comment: @Tonyk: As per problem, I'm only looking at top four selected out of n. I don't have a rule for how to apportion more than the top four to the two teams. If n is 4, I've already agreed with you.

Comment: @BruceET: In schoolyard team picking, everybody gets to play, don't they? That was my assumption, anyway.

Comment: @Tonyk: I assumed that at first, then read rules for 'Dodgeball' online and decided maybe not. Anyway we're not told the mechanism for choosing more than four. Counting captains, that would be two three-person teams. In retrospect, maybe I should have stopped there. I'll ponder it. Maybe I'll revise/simplify my Answer.